# What is the mean of "with more set to come"?

Tags: word-meaning, idioms

This is the sentence.

Tropical Storm Harvey dumped almost 50 inches (1.27 metres) of rain in some areas in just over four days, with more set to come.
(from : https://www.economist.com/blogs/graphicdetail/2017/08/daily-chart-19)

I think "with more set to come" is just a kind of adverbial phrase.

Of course, it might be one meaning chunk, but I want to know there is a specific thing or meaning that the "set" used in this phrase is pointing.

Comment: Think of it as something "set up" (prepared) to happen.

Answer (score 1):

> *Set to come* simply means "it is expected to arrive", "ready to arrive" or something impending.
>   Those words are bound together to form some phrasal verb and you shouldn't think of "set" outside that context.